# Display tagged services in Symfony ChoiceType

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I implemented a system that lets an admin configure some additional behaviors (that are actually Symfony Services) from a form. At the moment I was using an EntityType, in order to let the *admin* select *one or more* services from a table in the data base.

```
$builder->add('services', EntityType::class, array(
'class' => 'AppBundle:Services',
'multiple' => true,
));
```

But since I'm registering the services in *Symfony* itself I just thought that there should be a way to get the services from the container (or similar) and create a new *ServiceTagType* so I don't have to add them in both the `data base` and the `services.yml` and I can do something like:

```
$builder->add('services', ServiceTagType::class, array(
'tag' => 'some.service.tag',
'multiple' => true,
));
```

Reading here and there I found out that you can **tag** services but you can only get the *tagged services list* when the container is being compiled... I'm struggling trying to find a workaround but it's been no use.

Comment: In your compiler pass you can inject tagged service in your ServiceTagType and use ServiceTagType as service in your form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to create the **ServiceTagType** (I assume it will extend the [ChoiceType](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) and not the EntityType) :

How to create a custom type is documented [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html).

```
// src/AppBundle/Form/Type/ServiceTagType.php
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

class ServiceTagType extends AbstractType
{
    private $tags;

    public function setTags($tags)
    {
        $this->tags = $tags;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'choices' => $this->tags
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return ChoiceType::class;
    }
}
```

Register your **ServiceTagType** as a service (Because you need to provide the tags with [setter injection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/types.html#setter-injection))

```
# services.yml
app.form_type.service_tag:
    class: AppBundle\Form\Type\ServiceTagType
    tags:
        - { name: form.type }
```

Then, as Bourvill suggest, you can collect your tags in a [Compiler pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html#create-a-compiler-pass).

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

class TagsCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!$container->has('app.form_type.service_tag')) {
            return;
        }

        $definition = $container->findDefinition(
            'app.form_type.service_tag'
        );

        $taggedServicesIds = array_keys($container->findTaggedServiceIds(
            'app.tagged_for_service_tag_type'
        ));

        $taggedServices = array_fill_keys($taggedServicesIds ,$taggedServicesIds);

        $definition->addMethodCall('setTags',$taggedServices );
    }
}
```

And don't forget to [register this Compiler pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html#register-the-pass-with-the-container)

To register a CompilerPass in the FullStack Framework:

```
class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $container->addCompilerPass(new TagsCompilerPass());
    }
}
```